# Weird array assignment in MATLAB: [x,t]=house_dataset

Tags: arrays, matlab

I'm learning work with neural networks through MATLAB samples. In one sample of the documentation (R2012a), there is a weird assignment

```
[x,t] = house_dataset
```

**Basically**, house_dataset is a 13×506 2D array. But the assignment results in two arrays:
x, a 13×506 2D array which is to be used as input to our neural network; t a 1×506 array which is to be used as target for network.

I don't know how this is done. Is it based on some fundamental thing I don't know about MATLAB matrices?

I even assigned `house_dataset` into another variable

```
h_dataset = house_dataset;
```

and then MATLAB gave an error when I tried to do this:

```
[x,t] = h_dataset;
```

Error message reads:

```
>> [x,t] = h_dataset;
Too many output arguments.
```

Does anyone know what this is all about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal behaviour for functions (and house_dataset is one of many functions in toolbox)
Function returns 2 values

```
function [inputs,targets] = house_dataset
```

but if you just enter

```
 variable = house_dataset;
```

it returns and saves to variable only first value which is [inputs]

check the behaviour of very simple function

```
function [out1,out2] = test
    out1 = 'first out';
    out2 = 'second out';
end
```

and then call in matlab command window:

```
 [first, second] = test
 first = test
 second = test
```

if you want to get only second value use something like:

```
[~,second] = test
```